# Grails Domain Class how to accept null Values for Foreign keys

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Hi How Can I insert null values for a foreign key column

Can any one please explain

Answer (score 0):

- [Constraints Usage](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html)
- [nullable: true](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/nullable.html)